# How to display an external image in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to display an external image within a SSRS 2005 report, however I can't accomplish that. I've tried a lot of things but they just don't work.

I have a table in my report that displays a dynamic image based on code, I thought the error was in the code however it wasn't because I can see the image in BIDS, however when I try to display it on the report server or within an ASP.NET webpage it doesn't show up.

My Code is as follows:

```
Function ShowImage(value as Object) As String

  Dim strImg as String

If value < 0
    strImg= "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/24/traffic-lights-green-icon.png"
ElseIf value > 0
    strImg=  "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/24/traffic-lights-red-icon.png"
Else
    strImg=  "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/24/traffic-lights-yellow-icon.png"
End If

  Return strImg End Function
```

The value in my image control is as follows:

```
=Code.ShowImage(Fields!Diferencia_Entre_Importes.Value)
```

When I see the preview in BIDS it shows up the way it's supposed to be, but it doesn't happen in the report server.
As you see the images don't need any kind of authentication, besides that, I tried configuring the Execution Account with the same result (I just get a horrible X instead of the image)

I also tried setting the image's value as

```
http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/24/traffic-lights-green-icon.png
```

But had no success, also I tried using an image in the server in this way:

```
file:ImagePath
```

And had the same problem, using all of these solutions I can see the image in BIDS, but not in the Report Server.

Thank you very much

Comment: I am also a bit perplexed, but wonder why you are calling Code.ShowStatusImage instead of the function shown as ShowImage?

Comment: My bad, I'm calling Code.ShowImage, I'm editing the question right away

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is caused by an internet access issue on the account on the server running the SSRS report. Whether it is or not, I recommend saving those .png files locally on the server, and modifying the code accordingly - it should improve report performance as well as getting rid of this issue.

Comment: I've already tried that, if I use as image's value file:ImagePath, having the ImagePath in the server and I have the same result. I'm able to see them in BIDS, but not in ReportServer